# Best freeware to remove redeye in images?

Tags: images, processing

What is the best freeware application which can remove [red eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eye_effect) in images?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Picasa will do this.  Check out [this tutorial](http://www.photohowto.info/how-remove-red-eye-effect-using-picasa-2).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Paint.NET:

http://www.associatedcontent.com/video/29627/how_to_remove_red_eye_with_paintnet.html?cat=24

It is a built in option.

Answer (score 2):

**[Red Eye Remover Pro](http://www.vicman.net/redeyeremoverpro/index.htm)** does what it says on the tin :)

> Red Eye Remover Pro is
>   able to **automatically detect** and
>   **instantly correct** red pupils in your
>   photos.
>
> The program lets you work with large
>   collections of images at once, making
>   **batch red eye correction**  a snap!
>   Everything you need to do is to load
>   photos damaged by the red-eye effect
>   into the program and the program will
>   do the rest. To achieve the best
>   result, you can adjust the correction
>   options, watching the results in
>   real-time.

[image]

Red Eye Remover Pro is freeware.

Comment: This program seems to crash a lot if you load more than 50 photos...

Answer (score 1):

GIMP does it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

[photoshop.com](http://photoshop.com) can do this online

Answer (score 1):

[Faststone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDownload.htm). It's free!

Please check out my post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/41670/best-preferred-software-for-photography/43874#43874).

Some screenshots of its red eye removal utility:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, also Windows Live Photo Gallery (NOT the one installed with Vista, but the one downloaded from Live.com).